# Multiple calls to web services from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, asynchronous, soap

I'm building a prototype web application that, in response to a GET request with a query parameter, goes off and calls 3 different web services, all with different payloads - 2 are ReST (one returning a binary object, an image, one returning JSON), 1 is SOAP.

I then need to assemble data from each of these into an HTML page that is returned for the original GET request.

I'm new to asynchronous programming and I think that's where I'm going wrong.

For SOAP I'm using

```
var locationRequest = require('request');        
locationRequest(options1, function (error, response, output) {
...
}
```

For the ReST calls I'm using two similar calls like this:

```
    var resourceJSON;
    var body2;
    var resourceHttp = require("https");          
    var resourceRequest = resourceHttp.request(resourceOptions, function (resourceRes) {
        var chunks2 = [];        
        resourceRes.on("data", function (chunk2) {
            body2 += chunk2;
        });
        resourceRes.on("end", function () {                
            resourceJSON = JSON.parse(body2);
        });
        resourceRes.on('error', function (error) {
            console.log('\n Error received: ' + error);
    });
    resourceRequest.end();
});
```

These all take place within an Express app.get i.e.

```
app.get('/myURL', function(req,res,next){
}
```

Therefore, the last thing I need to do is to assemble those responses and return some HTML including the data to the caller.
Firstly I have some (rookie, I'm sure) weirdness going on with variable scope.  For example, if I define a variable to hold the JSON from the ReST call at the start of the app.get block, then write to it in the resourceRes.on("data...) function, I get a message that it's undefined if I reference it at the end of the app.et block.

Secondly, since these calls are all kicked of asynchronously, how do I determine that all have completed before assembling the data into my HTML response?

Any guidance or help much appreciated!

EDIT

So I've stripped this back to be as simple as I can as I'm getting an issue where, when I submit the request from the browser to kick the process off, the browser just waits with "waiting for localhost" and then eventually fails with a socket timeout error.  If I submit the request via Postman I get the JSON response as expected.  Any clues?

The code now looks like this:

```
app.get('/myurl', function(req,res,next){
var device = req.query.deviceId;
var resourceOptions = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": "myhostname",
    "port": 443,
    "path": "/mypath/",
    "headers": {
        "authorization": "Basic HIDINGTHIS",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "content-type": "application/json",      
    }
};

const resourceHttp = require("https");
const restRequest = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resourceHttp.request(resourceOptions, function (resourceRes) {
            var response = '';
            resourceRes.on("data", function (chunk2) {
                console.info('in on');  
                response += chunk2;
            });
            resourceRes.on("end", function () {
                console.info('in end');
                resolve(JSON.parse(response));
            });
            resourceRes.on('error', function (error) {
                console.info("in error");
                reject(error);
            });
            resourceRequest.end();
        });
    });
    return promise;
};

return restRequest()
.then(data => {
    // Send positive response from server
    console.info("succcess");
    res.end("DONE!");
})
.catch(err => {
    // Send negative response from server as there is an error
    console.info("error");
    res.end("ERROR!");
});     

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap these in a `Promise` and then use `Promise.all()` to run code once they have all returned:

```
app.get('/myURL', function(req, res, next){
    var soapPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        locationRequest(options1, function(error, response, output) {
            if (error) reject(error);
            else resolve(response);
        })
    });
    var restPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resourceHttp.request(resourceOptions, function(resourceRes) {
            var body = '';
            resourceRes.on("data", function (chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            resourceRes.on("end", function () {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            });
            resourceRes.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log('\n Error received: ' + error);
                reject(error);
            });
            resourceRequest.end();
        });
    });
    Promise.all([soapPromise, restPromise])
        .then(function([soapResult, restResult]) {
            //respond to client
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            //catch an error generated from either request
        })
})
```

Comment: Thank-you - In the Promise.all function you're using soapResult and restResult in your example.  Are they variables that are defined outside of the scope of the request blocks and I then populate within?

Comment: They are whatever the two promises resolve as. So in this case the first promise calls resolve(response) and the second one calls resolve(JSON.parse(body)). That means they will store whatever response was in the first callback and whatever JSON.parse(body) was in the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise, `.then()` and `.catch()` as follows:

```
  const locationRequest = require('request');
  const resourceHttp = require("https");

  const soapRequest = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      locationRequest(options1, function (error, response, output) {
        if(error)
          reject(error);
        else
          resolve(response);
      });
    });
    return promise;
  };

  const restRequest = () => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resourceHttp.request(resourceOptions, function (resourceRes) {
        var response = '';
        resourceRes.on("data", function (chunk2) {
          response += chunk2;
        });
        resourceRes.on("end", function () {
          resolve(JSON.parse(response));
        });
        resourceRes.on('error', function (error) {
          reject(error);
        });
        resourceRequest.end();
      });
    });
    return promise;
  };

  return soapRequest()
    .then(restRequest)
    .then(data => {
      // Send positive response from server

    })
    .catch(err => {
      // Send negative response from server as there is an error

    });
```

Comment: These won't run in parallel, though